# Django how to pass bulk values in html via for loop and array?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

**Views.py**

```
def cartdata(request):

    emailid = request.session['emailid']  
    dressid = cart_details.objects.values_list('dressid').filter(emailid=emailid)  
    cartdress = array.array('i',[dress_details.objects.all().filter(dress_id=dressid)])

    for i in cartdress:
        cartdetails = dress_details.objects.all().filter(dress_id=i)
        return render(request, 'project/shop.html', {'cartdetails':cartdetails})
```

**shop.html**

```
<div class="single-cart-item">{% for i in cartdetails %}
                    <a href="#" class="product-image">
                        <img src="{{ i.dress_image1 }}" class="cart-thumb" alt="">
                        <!-- Cart Item Desc -->
                        <div class="cart-item-desc">
                          <span class="product-remove"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <span class="badge">{{ i.dress_name }}</span>
                            <h6>{{ i.dress_type }}</h6>
                            <p class="size">Size:{{ i.dress_size }}</p>
                            <p class="color">Color: {{ i.dress_color }}</p>
                            <p class="price">RS.{{ i.dress_price }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>{% endfor %}
                </div>
```

**database**
in database 2 tables are there.
1st Cart table where 3 columns 1)cartid(primarykey) 2)email(session variable) 3)dressid(fetching from dress table)

2nd Dress table where all the data of dress available.

My main question is I'm not able to fetch whole data how can I fetch in djano.?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to loop through the cartdress, you can simply pass the ids in a tuple and have a filtered objects, like this:

```
def cartdata(request):

    emailid = request.session['emailid']  
    dressid = cart_details.objects.values_list('dressid').filter(emailid=emailid)  
    cartdress = array.array('i',[dress_details.objects.all().filter(dress_id=dressid)])
    cartdress = (1,2,3,4) # this should be the tuple of ids which you want to filter

    cartdetails = dress_details.objects.all().filter(dress_id=i)
    return render(request, 'project/shop.html', {'cartdetails':cartdetails})
```

Now in your html part, you could itirage the credentials and their items, like this:

```
             {% for carts in cartdetails %}
                    <div class="single-cart-item">
                                {% for i in carts %}
                    <a href="#" class="product-image">
                        <img src="{{ i.dress_image1 }}" class="cart-thumb" alt="">
                        <!-- Cart Item Desc -->
                        <div class="cart-item-desc">
                          <span class="product-remove"><i class="fa fa-close" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                            <span class="badge">{{ i.dress_name }}</span>
                            <h6>{{ i.dress_type }}</h6>
                            <p class="size">Size:{{ i.dress_size }}</p>
                            <p class="color">Color: {{ i.dress_color }}</p>
                            <p class="price">RS.{{ i.dress_price }}</p>
                        </div>
                    </a>{% endfor %}

                </div>
           {%endfor}
```

I hope this helps.